# Which components use the locale variables?

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

I have read that every process has a set of locale variables associated with it. For example, these are the locale variables associated with the `bash` process on my system:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I want to know who actually uses these locale variables.

Do the C standard functions (for example: `fwrite()`) and the Linux system calls use them? Does the behavior of some C standard functions or some Linux system call differ depending on the value of some locale variable?

Or is it only certain programs that can use these locale variables? For example, I can write a program that will display messages to the user in a different language depending on the value of the `LANG` locale variable.

Comment: The `"en_US.UTF-8"` is probably the character set to be used. That other locale variables have this value is strange. I would expect that Monetary would be `"$"` and Time would be the time format or the time zone. At least the timezone is used by the date & time library functions.

Comment: Perhaps [What Is a Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-2521/overview-39/index.html) can help.

Comment: The C language doesn't use the "environment list" itself. It's up to you to make use of it. For example you could use [`getenv`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv) to read `LC_COLLATE` and use it for a [`setlocale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) call and then use [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcoll) for locale-aware string comparisons.

Comment: POSIX systems will probably use it more frequently, maybe even internally in system calls. But you have to read the manual pages of the calls to find out.

Answer (score 12):

[By default, C's standard library functions use the "C" locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). You can switch it to the user locale to enable locale-specific:

- Character handling
- Collating
- Date/time formatting
- Numeric editing
- Monetary formatting
- Messaging

POSIX [`setlocale`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) documentation contains an incomplete list of locale-dependent functions affected by it:

> catopen, exec, fprintf, fscanf, isalnum, isalpha, isblank, iscntrl, isdigit, isgraph, islower, isprint, ispunct, isspace, isupper, iswalnum, iswalpha, iswblank, iswcntrl, iswctype, iswdigit, iswgraph, iswlower, iswprint, iswpunct, iswspace, iswupper, iswxdigit, isxdigit, localeconv, mblen, mbstowcs, mbtowc, newlocale, nl_langinfo, perror, psiginfo, setlocale, strcoll, strerror, strfmon, strftime, strsignal, strtod, strxfrm, tolower, toupper, towlower, towupper, uselocale, wcscoll, wcstod, wcstombs, wcsxfrm, wctomb

E.g.:

```
printf("%'d\n", 1000000000);
printf("Setting LC_ALL to %s\n", getenv("LANG"));
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // Set user-preferred locale.
printf("%'d\n", 1000000000);
```

Outputs:

```
1000000000
Setting LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8
1,000,000,000
```

Comment: @andreee Oops, did not notice `C` tag.

Comment: I removed the C++ namespacing to make it C, and the function-wrapping, which was extraneous.

Comment: What does the `'` flag in the format specifier do? It's non-standard.

Comment: @IanAbbott [It is a POSIX format specifier](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) for formatting with thousand grouping. An extension to the ISO C standard.

Comment: The list in this answe is incomplete. I believe the POSIX specifications for the functions in that list cover it *if you also dig though them all to find the other functions specified on the same page as each one*. An obvious omission is all the `printf` variants, but there are a good many more too, like mb/wc variants, etc.

Comment: @R.. True, this is why _POSIX setlocale documentation contains an **incomplete** list of locale-dependent functions affected by it_.

Answer (score 5):

> I have read that every process has a set of locale variables associated with it.

That's not really true, or at least it is highly over-simplified.

Many standard library functions (and non-standard library functions) modify their behaviour based on a set of locale configurations which are maintained in some hidden global object within the standard library implementation. (In some library implementations, the locale configuration is maintained per-thread rather than globally, using thread-local static variables.) That may seem to be associated with a process, since typically each process has a single instance of the standard library's runtime, but it's important to understand that -- despite appearances -- locale support is part of the library, not the OS kernel. (Of course, nothing in any standard defines where the kernel's boundaries are, or even what a kernel might be. You could run your program "bare metal" or you might have an OS which considers it useful to implement the standard library within system calls. I'm talking here about common cases.)

Basic locale configuration is defined by the C standard in section 7.11 (of the C11 standard), which defines two interfaces:

- `setlocale`, which modifies the library's locale configuration, and
- `localeconv`, which queries *part of* the locale configuration, allowing user code to conform to the locale's numeric formatting conventions (including monetary formatting).

The locale configuration is divided into a number of more-or-less independent components, called "categories". (The C++ standard library calls these "facets", which is also a commonly-used word.) There are five categories defined by the C standard and one more defined by Posix, but the categories are open-ended; individual standard library implementations are free to add additional categories. For example, the Gnu standard C library used on most Linux systems currently has a total of 12 categories. (See `man 7 locale` on your system for a current list.)

The standard categories are:

- `LC_CTYPE`:    Character classification and case conversion.
- `LC_COLLATE`:    Collation order.
- `LC_MONETARY`:    Monetary formatting.
- `LC_NUMERIC`:    Numeric, non-monetary formatting.
- `LC_TIME`:    Date and time formats.

and the Posix extension is:

- `LC_MESSAGES`:    Formats of informative and diagnostic messages and interactive responses.

Aside from `localeconv`, which only provides access to specific configurations from the `LC_NUMERIC` and `LC_MONETARY` categories, there is no way to query any specific configuration.

Also, there is no standard way at all to set a single configuration. All you can do is use `setlocale` to configure an entire category, using a library-dependent and non-standardised locale name (which is just a character string). More precisely, two locale names are standardised:

- The C standard defines the locale name `C`.
- Posix defines the locale name `POSIX`. However, Posix specifies that the corresponding locale shall be identical to the locale named `C`.

The details for locale-naming are (or should be) detailed in the `locale` documentation for the environment you're working in, but normally a locale-aware program will never call `setlocale` with a string constant other than the standard names, or the empty string. (I'll get to that in a minute.)

The `setlocale` interface allows the program to set an individual locale category, or to set all locale categories to the same locale name. It also returns a string which can be used to return to a previously configured locale category (or complete configuration).

The category names shown in the list of categories above are macros defined in `<locale.h>`. An additional macro, `LC_ALL`, is also defined by that header file: `LC_ALL`. One of these macros must be used as the first argument to `setlocale`.

The C and Posix standards both require that the initial locale setting on program startup is the `C` locale. Many aspects of the `C` locale are standardised (and somewhat more aspects of the `Posix` locale are standardised). This standardisation allows a programmer to predict how numeric conversions will work, for example.

But it is often the case that a programmer will want to interact with the program's user with that user's own locale preferences. It is obviously not desirable that every single program have its own idiosyncratic mechanism for determining what the user's locale preferences are, so the standard library provides a mechanism for setting the locale (or individual locale categories) to whatever the default locale is configured to: calling `setlocale` with the empty string (`""`) as a locale name. The C standard does not specify any particular mechanism for configuring this information; it merely assumes that one exists.

(Side note: Calling `setlocale` with an empty string as locale name is *not* the same as calling `setlocale` with `NULL` as locale name. `NULL` tells `setlocale` to not change any locale setting, but it will still return the string associated with the current locale. This avoids the need for a `getlocale` interface.)

Posix does specify a mechanism for configuring user preferences, and it also insists that (most) standardised command-line utilities operate in the default locale. That mechanism uses environment variables whose names correspond to the `setlocale` category macros.

On a Posix implementation, when the program calls `setlocale(LC_X, "");` the library will proceed to examine the current environment:

1. First, it looks for the environment variable `LC_ALL`. If that is defined and has a non-empty value, it is used to define the locale.
2. Otherwise, if the first argument to `setlocale` was not `LC_ALL` it looks for the environment variable whose name is the same as that argument. If that is defined and has a non-empty value, it is used to define the locale.
3. Otherwise, if the environment variable `LANG` is defined and has a non-empty value, it is used (in some implementation dependent way) to construct a locale name. (`LANG` is supposed to indicate the user's language, which is an important part of their locale preferences.)
4. Finally, some system-wide default is used.

Environment variables are generally initialised by the `login` program (or GUI equivalent) on the basis of system configuration files. (The precise mechanism varies from distribution to distribution and documentation is often difficult to find.)

As mentioned, almost all standard shell utilities are required by Posix to do the equivalent of `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` in order to operate in the user's configured locale. Every utility's manpage (or other documentation) should specify whether it does this or not, but it's reasonable to assume that it does unless there is some information to the contrary.

Also, many (but not all) standard library string functions are locale-aware. Library interfaces which are definitely not locale-aware include `isdigit` and `isxdigit`, which always respond on the basis of the `C` locale, and `strcmp`, which compares strings in the same way as `memcmp`, using the `char` value (interpreted as an `unsigned int`) to determine collation order. (`strcoll` is locale-aware, if you want to do comparison according to `LC_COLLATE`.) And the character encodings used for wide and multibyte characters are controlled (in some unspecified way) by the `LC_CTYPE` category.

Answer (score 4):

Many programs set the locale, and use it at least for internationalization.  Some specific examples:

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This is the locale for any category you didn’t specifically set to something else.  It allows the system to add new locale variables in a backward-compatible way.

```
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This selects which language’s sorting order is used on strings.  For example, *Ch* is considered a letter in Spanish and would come after *Cz*.  One C library function that uses it is `strcoll()`, and POSIX commands that do include `ls` (when you sort files by name) and `sort`.

```
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This determines the current character encoding.  In C11, you can set this and then use wide-character input and output, such as `wprintf()`.  The library will transparently convert between wide characters and the character set used by the outside world.  This still doesn’t quite work on Windows, unless you do some extra magic, but elsewhere, UTF-8 has become the standard.  An increasing number of programs, such as clang (as of version 7), no longer support anything but UTF-8.

```
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This determines what language and character set you see localized messages in.  In C on Unix/Linux, these would typically be loaded from a `.po` file by the `gettext` library.

```
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This affects how [`strfmon()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strfmon.html) formats monetary quantities.

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This determines the [formatting of numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4bmZ1gRqCc) that aren’t amounts of money.

```
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

This affects the formatting of time.  Try `LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8 date` in the shell to see an example.  (Or use `locale -a | grep UTF` to select some suitably-exotic locale.)  Also a good test of whether your timezone and `ntpd` are working properly.

```
LC_ALL=
```

Use `LANG` instead of this.  It sets every locale category at once, but it overrides the values in all the other locale variables.  It exists for backward compatibility.

For example, I use `LANG=en_US.utf8` on my Linux box, but I override `LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8` to get 24-hour time in English.  This would not be possible to do if `LC_ALL` were set.

`LANG` also allows your defaults to carry over into whatever other locale information your system supports, such as `LC_ADDRESS`, `LC_IDENTIFICATION`, `LC_RESPONSE`, `LC_MEASUREMENT` and `LC_TELEPHONE`.