# Where is the C code encode the bytes in the memory to the specific charset in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

In the [document of Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html):

> **LC_CTYPE**
>
> This category determines the interpretation of byte sequences as characters (e.g., single versus multibyte characters), character classifications (e.g., alphabetic or digit), and the behavior of character classes.  On glibc systems, this category also determines the character transliteration rules for iconv(1) and iconv(3).  It changes the behavior of the character handling and classification functions, such as isupper(3) and toupper(3), and the multibyte character functions such as mblen(3) or wctomb(3).

However, I see GCC's source code of `putwchar`:

```cpp
/* _IO_putwc_unlocked */
# define _IO_putwc_unlocked(_wch, _fp)                                        \
  (__glibc_unlikely ((_fp)->_wide_data == NULL                                \
                     || ((_fp)->_wide_data->_IO_write_ptr                \
                         >= (_fp)->_wide_data->_IO_write_end))                \
   ? __woverflow (_fp, _wch)                                                \
   : (wint_t) (*(_fp)->_wide_data->_IO_write_ptr++ = (_wch)))

/* putwchar */
wint_t
putwchar (wchar_t wc)
{
  wint_t result;
  _IO_acquire_lock (stdout);
  result = _IO_putwc_unlocked (wc, stdout);
  _IO_release_lock (stdout);
  return result;
}
```

There is no code using the locale set with `setlocale()`, which confuses me. When and where the bytes stored in the memory transit to the specific charset set by `setlocale()`?

**Update:**

```c
int main() {
    wchar_t wc = L'\x00010437';
    putwchar(wc); // print nothing
}
```

```c
int main() {
    wchar_t wc = L'\x00010437';
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    putwchar(wc); // print ''
}
```

In the two cases above, `setlocale()` affects the character displayed on the screen. I want to know in which process the bytes are determined to represent the specific character like ''?

**Update2:**

Maybe I find the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/wfileops.c.html#75) converting the multi-bytes data into the specific charset. Here is the code snippet in `_IO_wdo_write()` in [glibc/libio/wfileops.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/wfileops.c.html):

```c
/* Now convert from the internal format into the external buffer.  */
result = (*cc->__codecvt_do_out) (cc, &fp->_wide_data->_IO_state,
                                  data, data + to_do, &new_data,
                                  write_ptr,
                                  buf_end,
                                  &write_ptr);
```

Comment: What does `(_fp)->_wide_data->_IO_write_ptr` point to? What does `__woverflow` do?

Comment: A charset / character encoding is a scheme for mapping sequences of characters -- in a rather abstract sense -- to sequences of bytes.  To the extent that C's so-called character and wide character types actually represent characters, they provide an *encoded* representation, so there is no additional encoding needed or performed in conjunction with normal I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

> Where is the C code encode the bytes in the memory to the specific charset in Linux?

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't any.  A charset, a.k.a. character encoding, is a mapping from sequences of characters -- in a rather abstract sense of that term -- to sequences of bytes.  If you are looking at bytes in memory that represent character data then, perforce, you are looking at an already-encoded representation.  For a C program, they will normally be encoded according to the execution character set of the C implementation.

In particular, to the extent that C "character" and "wide character" types actually represent characters, they contain *encoded* character data.  There is normally no conversion needed or performed when such data are read or written, which is why you don't see it in the glibc source.

It is of course possible for a program to encode characters in some other encoding and store the resulting bytes in memory, via iconv(3), for example. It is then program's responsibility to ensure that they are handled appropriately.  As for mapping encoded byte sequences to a visual representation -- "glyphs" -- this is a function performed by the program that displays or prints them.  One way that is done is simply by selection of a font with appropriate mappings from byte sequences to glyphs.

Comment: As the code in the update, I want to know when the mechanism of the locale involves mapping the bytes into the specific item in the code page (charset).

Comment: @IvanaGyro, I have already answered this.  See my last paragraph.  But you need to understand that "the program that displays or prints [the glyphs]" is, for command-line programs such as you present, the terminal program that hosts your program.  Or in some cases it may be an actual hardware terminal, where the mapping from bytes to glyphs happens in hardware or firmware.

Comment: @John_Bollinger I understood your answer. Trying to not pass the output to stdout with the code `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "zh_TW.big5"); putwc(L'我', fopen("output.txt","w"));`

I found '我' was stored in BIG5, verifying with hex dump. And this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50609699/6663588) mentioned: `locale support is part of the library, not the OS kernel.`

It seems that there is a mechanism encodes the bytes into the target charset before sending out. Is there any extra info can help me verify your answer?

Comment: As for extra info, @IvanaGyro, apparently you know where to find the glibc source code.  That will at least tell you what glibc does.  Details may vary in other C standard libraries, but the broad strokes are likely to be the same.